# Trying to install cuda on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I want to install cuda for my course project, and I have a graphics driver version of 340.108 with nvidia GeForce GT 9800. I know that a higher version of the graphics driver is needed from this error message :

```
 libcuinj64-10.1 : Depends: libcuda1 (>= 418.39) or
                            libnvidia-tesla-cuda1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                            libcuda.so.1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                            libcuda-10.1-1
 libnvidia-ml-dev : Depends: libnvidia-ml1 (>= 418.39) or
                             libnvidia-tesla-440-ml1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                             libnvidia-tesla-418-ml1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable or
                             libnvidia-ml.so.1 (>= 418.39) but it is not installable
```

when I tried installing it through :

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

So, my doubt is that can I install the latest version of the driver using, say,

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
```

I would love to go ahead with the above command, but ubuntu-drivers devices recommends the 340 version and nothing above it. So if this is not possible, then please let me know how do I install cuda on my computer.
Thank you

Comment: Not possible, at all. CUDA can't be used with such old cards.

Comment: Look at older versions of CUDA, I think 8.0 will work with the 340 driver.  Probably won't make any difference for your course, but check with your instructor.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification, ChanganAuto and ubfan1.

Comment: The problem is that the requirement for older CUDA toolkit version will probably lead to downgrade in the operating system. I'm currently sifting through forums online for any working info on getting CUDA 8.0 toolkit to work on Ubuntu 20.04 and it's a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub

wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin

sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600

sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install cuda

echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

check version:-

```
nvcc --version
```

ref: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-linux/

how to run cuda code is also in above blog.